# Replace values of empty dictionaries in a dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, replace

Given the following:

```py
data = pd.DataFrame({"a": [{}, 1, 2]})
```

How best to replace `{}` with a particular value?

The following works:

```py
rep = 0
data.apply(lambda x: [y if not isinstance(y, dict) else rep for y in x])
```

but I'm wondering if there's something more idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

Try with bool empty object will return False

```
data.loc[~data.a.astype(bool),'a'] = 0 
data
Out[103]: 
   a
0  0
1  1
2  2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pd.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) with `errors='coerce'`:

```
In [24]: data['a'] = pd.to_numeric(data['a'], errors='coerce').fillna(0).astype(int)

In [25]: data
Out[25]: 
   a
0  0
1  1
2  2
```